# Amplify backend and db

Tags: node.js, angular, database, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Im still learning to deploy websites and i got an dev intership on a company, despite they dont have an dev. So I created an frontend on angular and the backend on node.js, its working and sending the data to mongodb. My question is how do i deploy the site online? I wanted to try amplify and could deploy the frontend, but i dont know how to connect it to my backend, also about the data I tried to create an exemple of what the data would look like on amplify but it doesnt have an object or array type, the data would be something like that:

```
key: string;
tableName: string;
debito: {
masterCard: { valor: number },
visa: { valor: number },
outros: { valor: number },
}
```

can I deploy my front and backend together on amplify? and can i store the data exactly the way my code is making or if i dont, can i still use another db like mongo?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Ampify to deploy apps to AWS. Instead, I would look at writing an AWS Serverless solution that can use Angular/React (or other front ends).  You can deploy a front end app using S3/Cloud Front. The client app can invoke backend logic using API Gateway.

To learn how to write a serverless solution using AWS (and how to deploy it), see this solution:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_javascript_3_topic.html)

More information about this solution, see:

https://community.aws/posts/cloud-journeys/01-serverless-image-recognition-app